# "&=" operation in C error

Tags: c, pointers, bit-manipulation

i have an array of tam=1000 and i have to check if i receive all elements

```
bool ok = true;
size_t i;
size_t tam=1000;
for (i = 0; i < tam; i++){
    ok &= vector_obtener(vec_vol, i, &valor);
    if (i!=valor)      //this if was something i added to check why it wasn't working.
        printf("En i=%zu y valor=%i \n",i,valor);
    ok &= (valor == i);
}
print_test("all good", ok);
```

vector_obtener receives the array, the position and a pointer to save the info. If the position is correct it should save the data in the pointer and return true.
 With the if i used above i checked if something was missing, but it printed from 0 to 999 as it should.

```
bool vector_obtener(vector_t *vector, size_t pos, int *valor){
    if (pos>(vector->tam)-1 || (vector->tam==0))
        return false;
    *valor=vector->datos[pos];
    if(!*valor)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
```

Here is the print_test:

```
void print_test(char* name, bool result){
    printf("%s: %s\n", name, result? "OK" : "ERROR");
}
```

EDIT: ok added. ok should be true when it enters print_test.

PS: Sorry if im not too clear, english is not my mother language. If you dont understand something i will try to put it in another way.

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? Is there an error? If yes, what is it?

Comment: Show declaration of `ok` and its  initialization.

Comment: This `if (i!=valor)` is checking that the position in the data isn't the same of the value of the data in that position (should happen rarely i imagine). How you initialize variable `ok` and what you expect to check with that `if`?

Comment: Minor : `printf("En i=%zu y valor=%i \n",i,valor);` should use `"En i=%d y valor=%i \n"`.

Comment: There are multiple problems with your example code.  For example, you declare i to be an int and valor to be a int pointer.  Then, at one point you test for valor == i.

Comment: NetVipeC the if was just to check if it was ok, i will delete it once i figure out where is the mistake.

Comment: `if(!*valor) return false;` : return false if *valor == 0,  `ok &= (valor == i);` : if i == 0 then must valor == 0 (to be false), So ok is always false at `print_test("all good", ok);`.

Comment: fpmurphy1 My bad, i and tam are both size_t

Comment: @fpmurphy1 in the first block `valor` is an int, and in the second block (a different function), `valor` (a local variable to that function) is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are updating the `ok` variable 2000 times before printing the `ok` variable at the end of the loop, it's hard to tell where exactly the error occurred.  To diagnose the problem you should check the value of the `ok` variable every time it gets updated

```
for (i = 0; i < tam; i++)
{
    ok &= vector_obtener(vec_vol, i, &valor);
    if ( !ok )
        printf("vector_obtener failed at i=%zu\n", i);

    ok &= (valor == i);
    if ( !ok )
        printf("En i=%zu y valor=%i \n",i,valor);
}
```

If BLUEPIXY is correct, it will print an error message when `i == 0` because either

```
if(!*valor)
    return false;
```

or

```
ok &= (valor == i);
```

is going to fail when `i == 0`

Answer (score 0):

From staring at your code a good bit, it appears that you are attempting to insure that every element of the array, vec_vol, is initialized with it's index.  If this assumption is correct, this code should do that:

```
bool ok = true;
size_t i;

if(NULL != vec_vol)
{
    for (i = 0; i < vec_vol->tam; i++)
    {
        if(vec_vol->datos[pos] != i)
        {
            ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if(ok)
{
    print_test("all good", ok);
}
```

If I missed the intent of you code, please ignore this.